# Ionic - change default style to Android style instead Ios style

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I bought a template for Ionic from some place , and all the elements are adjust for Ios device, even when I installed it on a Android device.

I use Ionic 3.9.2 and cordova  8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

How can I changed it?

I added to the index.html this code:

```
<ion-app class="md"></ion-app>
```

But it doesnt work.

this is my config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.arbestech.instantdeal" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Instant Deal</name>
    <description>Instant Deal</description>
    <author email="" href="#">Instant Deal</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.55:8101" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.5:8101" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="^2.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="^1.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="es6-promise-plugin" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^1.9.1">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="InstantDeal" />
        <variable name="API_VERSION" value="v1.1" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-accountkit" spec="^1.4.0">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="InstantDeal" />
        <variable name="CLIENT_TOKEN" value="" />
        <variable name="API_VERSION" value="v1.1" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="^5.3.0">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="‏" />
    </plugin>
    <allow-navigation href="http://10.0.0.16:8100" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
</widget>
```

I search over the internet but still unable to solve it

I dont exactly know which files should I attach to this question so if I need to 
paste another file let me know 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have done this to one of my projects before to make the package lighter, as shown here.
https://julienrenaux.fr/2017/07/20/optimized-ionic-angular-css-bundle-for-pwas/

You might only be building for iOS. You can check and see if there is a config for ionic_sass in the package.json.

Example

```
"config": {
   "ionic_sass": "./sass.js"
}
```

Then within the linked file in this case called sass.js
look for something like

```
/**
 * excludeFiles: An array of regex patterns for files which
 * should be excluded. If a file matches both include and exclude
 * patterns, then the file will be excluded.
 */
excludeFiles: [
  /\.(wp|md).(scss)$/i
],
```

If you remove the md (Android) you should see the default Ionic sass styling be applied. I hope this is all it is, otherwise I would have to keep guessing.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the article re this: IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { mode: 'md' // 'md' | 'ios' | 'wp' }). Basically this is the most important config change. The rest is more to optimize and lighten up css package.